# Trigger logic to send emails not executed when referencing related objects

Tags: apex, email

I'm trying to send an email to a user when a new custom object is created.

This currently doesn't work in the sandbox. Are there any special settings that need to be enabled or is there a bug is the code? I checked Email Administration and 'All Emails' is enabled.

Thanks for any help

P.S. I know I can also do a workflow rule, but the next step is to also send an email when deleted so need to have some code working either way.

```
/* Send Email to MDR when they are added to Whatever object. 
*
* @author me - code taken from sfdc99.com
*/

trigger sendEmailtoEMDR on Whatever_object__c (after insert) {

  List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

  for (Whatever_object__c newTT : Trigger.new) {

    if (newTT.Assigned_User__r.Email != null && newTT.Assigned_User__r.FirstName != null && 
        newTT.CreatedBy.Email != null && newTT.CreatedBy.FirstName != null) {

      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

      List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
      sendTo.add(newTT.Assigned_User__r.Email);
      mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);

      mail.setReplyTo(newTT.CreatedBy.Email);
      mail.setSenderDisplayName(newTT.CreatedBy.FirstName);

      List<String> ccTo = new List<String>();
      ccTo.add('an_email@gmail.com');
      mail.setCcAddresses(ccTo);

      mail.setSubject('A new Whatever Object was assigned to you: ' + newTT.Account__r.Name);
      String body ='<html><body>'+ newTT.Assigned_User__r.FirstName + ', <br><br>' + 
      newTT.CreatedBy.FirstName + 'assigned' + newTT.Account__R.Name + 'as a new Whatever object';
      mail.setHtmlBody(body);

      mails.add(mail);
    }
  }

  Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
}
```

Comment: Have you made sure the email address of the user is correct?   In the Sandbox the email address adds a '.sandboxname' to the end of the email address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Trigger, the value of `newTT` will not have access to `assigned_user__r` fields. The trigger.new List only knows about the fields in Whatever_object__c, not any relationship fields, these have to be queried for as in:

```
Map<ID,Whatever_obj__c> woIdToWhateverMap = new Map<ID,Whatever_obj__c> (
      [select id, assigned_user__r.email, assigned_user__r.firstName, ...
         where id IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()]);
```

Then use the map to do your test for email eligibility as in

```
for (Whatever_obj__c wo : Trigger.new) {
   Whatever_Obj__c newTT = woIdToWhateverMap.get(wo.id);
   if (newTT.Assigned_User__r.Email != null && newTT.Assigned_User__r.FirstName != null && 
       newTT.CreatedBy.Email != null && newTT.CreatedBy.FirstName != null) {
   ... build the email
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick.

Interesting that I could save that query in the Whatever_obj__c custom object, even though there aren't specific fields for assigned_user__r.email, firstname etc.

Answer (score 2):

Check your email settings to make sure that all types of email are enabled. Sandboxes have non-system emails, like workflow and apex email, turned off by default when they are created/refreshed.

To check your email settings, go to Setup > Email Administration > Deliverability and make sure the access level is set to All Email.